# Joining two tables by selection from one table in MapInfo?

Tags: sql, mapinfo, attribute-joins

I have 2 MapInfo tables that have a corresponding unique ID number field.
I'd like to be able to manually select some objects from one table and join the 2 tables based on a matching unique ID number for the selected objects only.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You do it like regular SQL, but use the MapInfo user interface.

Here's an example: http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-sep-2012/Query-Ninja-Joining-Tables

And here's an image showing how (from the above URL).

[image: Sourced from PitneyBowes website 2016]

EDIT:

In order to achieve the result you're after, try these steps:

1. First join the two tables together by selecting * for 'select columns' your two tables in the 'from tables' and setting table1.id = table2.id (where table and id are replaced by actual values) in the 'where condition' field.
2. If step 1 works, you should see a table with all the info you're after and you can do a select from this table to get your 20 records.
3. Once step 2 works, you may like to revisit step one to do it all in one go!

Comment: Thank you Alex, I'm struggling to apply this methodology to my query though. I'll provide a little more detail. Table A and Table B have objects with a matching unique ID number. Table A contains 100 records with owner and address information. Table B contains 50 records with a property ID number. I want to select for example 20 records from Table B and join the 20 selected records to the 20 matching records in Table A. The result would be a  table with 20 records containing the owner & address records from Table A and the property ID number from Table B.

Comment: You can definitely do this, @CraigT. I don't have a copy of MapInfo currently, so I can't work the example fully. You can do it in stages, though, which should be easy. I'll edit my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: This works perfectly Alex, appreciate your assistance.